# Add angular 4 property from typescript component

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I need to add the **angular 4** click-event binding **(click)** in an HTML element from TS Component.
Here the code:

```
$('.swiper-wrapper').append('<div class="swiper-slide basic-button" (click)="goToComponent(\'home/labels/\'' + label.id + ')" style="background-image: url(' + label.image + '); height: 300px; width: 300px;"></div>')
```

In **angularJs** i would use **$compile**, but in angular 4?
Don't answer me with [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960) because i don't understand the explanation.

It would be so useful if someone can explain me how to do this thing step by step (i'm new in **Angular 4**).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to add the element?

Comment: You want to append an element or bind the `(click)` function ? Please elaborate what you want to achieve ...

Comment: Hi Venomy, because with the Swiper library i had problem with have dynamic managing of images with ngFor

Comment: Hi Ante, i have a Swiper slider and i want to manage it dinamicaly (add and remove images). I want to add the click event to these images, where when i click one of them, i will be go in a specific route

Comment: why not add the click method separately, when the element has been added to DOM? That would make a "compile" not necessary, the rest of the html having no other angular code

Comment: Hi Kaddath, how can i do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2). Kindly check the all answers. it has been solutions for your question. take some times to understand those answers

Comment: there are (a bit more complicated) solutions proper to angular, but if your case is simple, you should be able to use good old JS `addEventListener`; the function you bind will be defined in your scope, so it will be parsed by angular and can contain angular code.